# Out of memory on resource loading for Android game

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a game that so far has to work with about ~200 PNGs totaling ~14 MB, all with sizes ranging from 250x150 to 600x400 (these are xhdpi drawables, right now I'm letting android do the resizing for lower dpi).

The problem is that if I load them all when the game starts, I get an out of memory error after about 20 seconds, both on the emulator (with 1 GB RAM) and on a Galaxy S device (512 MB RAM).

I've seen games with much bigger resources, some even in the hundreds of MB. How do these handle loading their resources fast without exceeding the memory constraints? 14 MB shouldn't be that much.

Right now I'm using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` to load every bitmap inside a few for loops before the game starts. I also tried using a `BitmapFactory.Options` with `inSampleSize` set to 4, which fixes the out of memory problem, but not the slow loading, which still takes about 20 seconds. I would also rather not have to do this, because if I make the images 4 times smaller there is little point in accounting for hdpi and xhdpi screens at all - quality will be a lot worse on these. I also tried using `getDrawable()`, but it made no difference.

I also considered loading each resource as it is needed (after the game has started), but:

1. Wouldn't this be slow? - right now the system allocates more memory pretty much between each load, which takes 100-300 ms. This would seriously slow down my frame rate.
2. If I cache each image so it's only loaded once, eventually I will need all of them in the same level, so this shouldn't fix the out of memory error.

I know a bitmap takes more space in memory than the PNG on the disk - I get the error when allocating about 40 MB. Isn't there a way to just load the 14 MB in memory and build bitmaps from them as they are needed, or something that gives up a little speed (it's a pretty basic 2d game so I don't really need a lot of processing power or max fps) in exchange for a lot more free memory?

Also, I have a lot of small animations with about 10-16 frames. Each one is a separate file. Would there be any benefit in merging them in one single file and loading that? I can't see it helping with memory usage, but could it help with loading times?

**Update**: I changed my code to load each frame, display it, and then recycle() it. This leads to what I can tell is < 5 FPS, so I don't think I can do this

Comment: Are you sure you need all these images in every moment of your game?

Comment: @Egor - They won't all be on the screen at the same time since most of them are frames for about 10 distinct objects, which can be on the screen at the same time. But in an interval of, say 2-3 seconds, there's a very good chance most if not all of them will be displayed.

Comment: The main issue is that on many devices (and emulator, I believe), the heap size is only 16 MB.  When you load 14 MB of images into memory using BitmapFactory, each of the images is decoded into a bitmap, thus far exceeding the 16 MB of allocated memory.  If you really do need to have such large images, you'll need to find a way to load/release them on the fly as they are needed.  Otherwise, you'll have to work with smaller bitmaps.  Also, keep in mind that loading smaller size images is MUCH, MUCH faster than loading large images and have Android scale them down.

Comment: @Aleks G - are you sure about the 16 MB limit? The emulator seems to grow the heap up to ~44 MB before crashing. I haven't tried it yet, but I can't really imagine loading the images from resources and then releasing them allowing me to keep a decent FPS. Maybe I will have to resize them, but I'm still hoping there's a better way.

Comment: **Update**: I changed my code to load each frame, display it, and then `recycle()` it. This leads to what I can tell is < 5 FPS, so I don't think I can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try expanding your option (2) with a SoftReference cache of Bitmaps. That way, you would load your Bitmap only once, but if the VM is low on memory this would be the first candidate to be freed. Something like this:

```
public class MemoryCache {
    private HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache=new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        if(!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;
        SoftReference<Bitmap> ref=cache.get(id);
        return ref.get();
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
    }

    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```